# Why does equal resistance and capacitive reactance lead to 70,7% of the output signal?

Tags: filter

I think I'm somewhere half way through to understand it.

Considering an ordinary voltage divider like this:

[image: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/fil75.gif]

the output voltage is independent of the frequency and is equal to the ratio of these two resistors.

Going through to passive filters there is somehow an analogy, which is a bit misleading.

[image]

I know that the capacitive reactance depends on the frequency according to the equation:

$$X_C = \frac{1}{2\pi fC} [\Omega]$$

So following the idea of the voltage divider, I would expect the output voltage to be at 50% of the input voltage, but it is not the case. For some reason you have to use the impedance like:

$$V_{out} = V_{in} \frac{X_C}{\sqrt{R^2 + X_C^2}} = V_{in}\frac{X_C}{Z}$$

and it leads to the output voltage of 70,7%, when the resistance and the capacitive reactance are equal.

What have I missed?

Comment: Have you studied any AC analysis? Particularly, RMS voltage, phasors, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Here's what you assert (correctly): -

\$V_{OUT} = V_{IN} \dfrac{X_C}{\sqrt{R^2 + X_C^2}} = V_{IN}\dfrac{X_C}{Z}\$

Let's take the example of R and Xc being equal in magnitude. What does this make the denominator: -

\$\sqrt{R^2 + X_C^2} = \sqrt{2R^2}\$ (because Xc = R)

Therefore the denominator becomes \$\sqrt2\cdot R\$ and the R cancels with the R (or the Xc) in the numerator hence,

\$V_{OUT} = \dfrac{V_{IN}}{\sqrt2}\$

Pythagorous is the reason why the R term and Xc term are squared - an R and a C do not form a potential divider like an R and an R - the impedance of a capacitor is at right angles to the impedance of a resistor.

Answer (score 6):

You missed a *j*, the root of -1.

The impedance offered by a capacitor is \$-jX_c\$ not \$X_c\$. So writing the voltage divider formula,

$$V_o = \frac{-jX_c}{R - jX_c}\times V_{in}$$
at \$R=X_c\$,
$$\frac{V_o}{V_{in}} = \frac{-j}{1- j} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\angle\frac{-\pi}{4}$$
$$|V_o| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\times|V_{in}| = 0.707\ |V_{in}|$$

Answer (score 4):

I liked this question, simple but it made me think for a second.  I had to slap a circuit together.
Here's a 'scope shot of the voltage across a 0.1uF cap and 1.6k ohm resistor in series.
at 1 kHz.

[image]